# Как установить таймер в функции jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть такой код:

```
function hoverMe() {
    $('.rubberBand').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('magictime twisterInDown');

        //тут должен быть таймаут в 2секунды 

        $(this).removeClass('magictime twisterInDown');


    });
}
```

На месте комментария должен быть таймаут, что бы класс удалился после исполнения анимации

Спасибо

Comment: `$(this).addClass('magictime twisterInDown').delay(2000).removeClass('magictime twisterInDown');`

Comment: не работает 
не проходит анимация

Comment: добавьте пример воспроизводящий проблему на jsfiddle или тут с помощью сниппета. Анимация прописана в css?

Comment: конечно
она работает если не добавлять removeClass
но срабатывает только один раз

Comment: @splash58 delay() только для animate(), не?

Comment: то есть отдельно вынести ремум, а дилей оставить на эд класс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-гомосячьи выглядит, но на скорую руку.
Насколько я понял `delay()` делает задержку только между методами анимации (`animate()`) и только, к которой `addclass()` не относится.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  .magictime {
   border: 2px solid red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(function() {
    $('.rubberBand').hover(function() {
     $(this).addClass('magictime twisterInDown');
     setTimeout(rem, 2000);

    }, function() {});
   });

   function rem() {
    $('.rubberBand').removeClass('magictime twisterInDown');
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="rubberBand">lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: хаахах, ничего не по гомосячьи))
спасибо)